# Expresso-Store Email Template - more than 1 BCC address?

Tags: expresso-store

Can I add more than one bcc email address to the Expresso-Store Email Template? In case I can, should i use comma between the address'?

Answer (score 3):

Yup the BBC field allows a comma delimited list of email addresses.